# Are computerized versions of board and card games on topic?

Tags: discussion, computer-questions

With the proliferation of tablets, there have been several board games ported to the medium, that either by hot seat play, or using the tablet as a board, can be utilized in place of the actual game.  These games sometimes have adapted rules that are different from the rules of the physical board games.

**Is it OK to ask questions about the specific rules of such games?  And should they be tagged with the same tag as the physical game if so?**

Comment: Related: [Gaming has recently brought up this topic as well](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4495/what-do-we-do-about-video-games-which-are-true-to-source-emulations-of-real-life). It may be of interest to try to coordinate our policies in this case so we don't end up with unacceptable migrations in either direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is addressed directly in our [FAQ](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/faq),

> Questions about computer implementations of board games are fine.

I don't see any reason for separate tags in the general case.

Computer implementations for board games are most likely on topic both here **and** and [Gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com), and [that's OK](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/).  I wouldn't be encouraging migrations either way.  Whichever site the questioner uses is fine and folks will likely get quality answers wherever they ask it.

Comment: I guess the reason I ask about separate tags is that the computer implementation can be subtly different than the physical one, and I thought it might get confusing in that respect, especially when searching for an answer.

Comment: @wraith808 - I guess the question I would ask is "Are both groups (computerized and regular) likely to benefit from questions in the other group?"  In most cases I think the answer is positive.  If so, then we shouldn't seek to split the groups, especially prematurely before either one gets a significant number of questions.  Instead, we can note differences/problems on the tag wiki.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are on topic and are a great fit for the site.

Yes, they should be tagged with the same physical board game tag, and they should also use the [computers](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computers) tag.

If there are any differences between the computer implementation, and the physical implementation, when users answer the question they should use knowledge of the computer implementation if possible, or should note that their expertise comes from the board game not the computer.

Answers can always be corrected in the future if it is found that the computer implementation is different.

Comment: I'm not sure how this site treats secondary tags, but I know on Gaming we would definitely frown on using the computers tag to modify the board game tag like this.

Comment: Gaming only allows 1 tag? Why? For example, what if a question was about 2-player strategy for Street Fighter II (fireball trap), specificly and not about playing against the computer. Wouldn't you tag it 2 player or multiplayer. Visa versa, wouldn't you tag a question about beating a computer opponent differently, with computer or AI, etc.

Comment: There's lots of discussion about this on Gaming's meta.  This is a good summary, http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3320/how-should-i-tag-on-gaming-se-are-genre-tags-used/3321#3321

Comment: @bwarner, I don't think the link post applies. Computer implementations marked with the computer tag help identify several key differences between a physical implementation. The linked post is more analogous to publisher (what specific differences are there when playing Cosmic Encounter by Fantasy Flight). I would argue that rules changes are the heart of many questions, and if rules differences exist between a PC and board game a tag denoting the difference is useful.